# execute 2 MySql query using timer in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, timer

How can i execute 2 `mysql query` using `ThreadingTimer`?I want 1st timer update data in db and 2nd timer count how much data are updated and also show in label in windows form.Here is my code,

```
   void PrepareTimers(List<int> _dataValues)
   {
        foreach (int dataValue in _dataValues)
        {
            timer = new ThreadingTimer (new TimerCallback(TimerAction), dataValue, 0, 2000);
            timer1 = new ThreadingTimer(new TimerCallback(TimerAction1), dataValue, 0, 2000);

            //Console.WriteLine("Timer " + dataValue + " created.");


        }
    }
    void TimerAction(object flag)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Timer start "+ flag.ToString());
        string myconstring = "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=alicosms;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=;";
        MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(myconstring);
        string u = "UPDATED";
        mycon.Open();
        //Console.WriteLine("Timer " + flag.ToString() + " : " + "UPDATE sms_data_bankasia set flag= @flag * 2 , sendingstatus = '" + u + "' WHERE flag = " + flag.ToString() + "  LIMIT 1");
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE sms_data_bankasia set flag= @flag * 2 , sendingstatus = '" + u + "' WHERE flag = " + flag.ToString() + " LIMIT 1", mycon);
        MySqlParameter param = new MySqlParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@flag";
        param.Value = flag;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        mycon.Close();                                  
    }

    void TimerAction1(object flag)
    {
        string myconstring = "SERVER=localhost;" + "DATABASE=alicosms;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=;";
        MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(myconstring);
        string sql = "SELECT count(flag) FROM sms_data_bankasia where sendingstatus='UPDATED' group by flag";
        MySqlCommand comd = mycon.CreateCommand();
        comd.CommandText = sql;
        mycon.Open();
        MySqlDataReader dtr = comd.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            while (dtr.Read())
            {
                dict[timer] = label;
                dict[timer].Text = dtr[0].ToString() + " program Updated";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        mycon.Close();
    }
```

It provide `error,"cross thread operation not valid".` What should i do? Any good suggestion?

Comment: What line throw that exception? My guess is it's because you try to change something in the UI while not on the UI thread.

Comment: In TimerAction1 catch throw that exacption @arkain.So what should i do?

Comment: Is it thrown from the MessageBox.Show? or is it just caught there?

Comment: it is thrown in MessageBox @arkain

Answer (score 0):

In Windows forms, you cannot do anything in the UI from any other thread than the UI-thread.
Your timer is running your code on a seperate thread.

You could try to use the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` instead, as it will marshal the event handling back to the UI thread for you.

Answer (score 0):

[Here you can read about the solution](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AvoidingInvokeRequired.aspx)

Just to test if it fixes your issue try wrapping your MessageBox call in code like this:

```
public delegate void StringDelegate(string message);

private void ShowMessageBox( string message )
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke( new StringDelegate( ShowMessageBox, new object[] { message } ));
        return;
    }

    MessageBox.Show( message );
}
```

This is written partly from memory, so it might vary a little.

Comment: Replace MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); with the method I wrote

Comment: Replace MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) into the catch with your code?It provide error.

Comment: what error, you need to be more specific, keep in mind I wrote it from memory you may have to change it if there are compiler errors

Comment: I don't understand your code clearly. For this i don't understand where i change to avoid compiler error

Comment: I made a change do that work? but really you just have to look at what parameters are possible, I don't remember and cant check it atm. It just a normal delegate, you can even make it anonymous if you like that better. Look at the link I send, it will explain in more detail.